# Are there any Stack Overflow Java projects available?

Tags: discussion

The reason I am asking you this question is I seem to get very definitive and direct answers to my Java questions from your site while I resolve questions on my Java projects.

I am currently working through Java projects on Javaranch.com and I was wondering whether stackoverflow.com is considering a similar slew of Java projects for those who want to manipulate the language and not just read books about it. Javaranch refers to these projects as their "Cattle Drive" if you would like to review it. The projects are great for an experienced IT person and cover important Java concepts such as data structures, JSP/Servlets, JDBC, Classes and Objects etc. And all of this learning happens without losing the 3-5 semesters of TIME that could be required in Java classes.

I am learning a lot by actually resolving these programming problems while manipulating the Java language and I wonder if your site is considering offering anything similar.

Answer (score 5):

> I am learning a lot by actually resolving these programming problems while manipulating the Java language and I wonder if your site is considering offering anything similar?

Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. The community here helps people with specific problems, and does not undertake projects like modifying Java (or any other language for that matter) as a whole. If any one member is attempting something like this and encounters a problem while doing so, he/she may post a question to help resolve that specific problem.

From what I can see from by brief viewing of Java Ranch, it is a site where in addition to helping people with problems, you have challenges, tutorials and code reviews with other members. Stack Overflow does not have any such system in place for holding challenges or posting full tutorials on the site itself.

For code review type questions, consider visiting Stack Overflow's sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).